# show tweets inside div from an asynchronous request

Tags: javascript

Am trying to laod tweets into a div after looping them from yahoo placemaker. They are loading on the div but the information shown by them is placemaker's last result.

This is the code..

```
            function getLocation(user, date, profile_img, text,url) {
            var templates = [];
            templates[0] = '<div><div></div><h2 class="firstHeading">'+user+'</h2><div>'+text+'</div><div><p><a href="' + url + '"target="_blank">'+url+'</a></p></div><p>Date Posted- '+date+'</p></div>';
            templates[1] = '<table width="320" border="0"><tr><td class="user"  colspan="2" rowspan="1">'+user+'</td></tr><tr><td width="45"><a href="'+profile_img+'"><img src="'+profile_img+'" width="55" height="50"/></a></td><td width="186">'+text+'<p><a href="' + url + '"target="_blank">'+url+'</a></p></td></tr></table><hr>';
            templates[2] = '<div><div></div><h2 class="firstHeading">'+user+'</h2><div>'+text+'</div><div><p><a href="' + url + '"target="_blank">'+url+'</a></p></div><p>Date Posted- '+date+'</p></div>';
            templates[3] = '<table width="320" border="0"><tr><td class="user"  colspan="2" rowspan="1">'+user+'</td></tr><tr><td width="45"><a href="'+profile_img+'"><img src="'+profile_img+'" width="55" height="50"/></a></td><td width="186">'+text+'<p><a href="' + url + '"target="_blank">'+url+'</a></p></td></tr></table><hr>';
                        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                Placemaker.getPlaces(text, function (o) {
                    console.log(o);
                    if (!$.isArray(o.match)) {
                        var latitude = o.match.place.centroid.latitude;
                        var longitude = o.match.place.centroid.longitude;
                        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            icon: profile_img,
                            title: user,
                            map: map,
                            position: myLatLng
                        });

                      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                          content: templates[0].replace('user',user).replace('text',text).replace('url',url).replace('date',date)
                      });
                      var $tweet = $(templates[1].replace('%user',user).replace(/%profile_img/g,profile_img).replace('%text',text).replace('%url',url));
                      $('#user-banner').css("visibility","visible");$('#news-banner').css("visibility","visible");
                      $('#news-tweets').css("overflow","scroll").append($tweet);
                      function openInfoWindow() {
                          infowindow.open(map, marker);
                      }
                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', openInfoWindow);
                      $tweet.find(".user").on('click', openInfoWindow);
                        bounds.extend(myLatLng);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Where is your loop? This sounds like the common "closure inside loop" problem. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example.

Comment: i dont understand this closures.can u help me figure out how to solve this?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. You have to provide more information (about the input, resulting HTML, etc) and / or a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Ok i will try to give some more information tomorrow . thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ak,

After some experimentation, I tracked down the problem to `Placemaker.js` not being able to handle multiple simultaneous requests. It's tempting to think you can overcome the problem with closures to remember loop-generated data but this doesn't work. The fix needs to be within `Placemaker` and I opted to refactor it as a jQuery plugin. jQuery affords the possibility of returning a `promise` from the `getPlaces` method, making it similar to jQuery's native `$.ajax()`, `$.get()` etc.

### Yahoo! Placemaker.js as a jQuery Plugin

```
/* ******************************************************************************
 * Yahoo! Placemaker.js factored as a jQuery Plugin
 * ******************************************************************************
 * by Beetroot-Beetroot: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1142252/beetroot-beetroot
 * ******************************************************************************
 * For example of usage, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253544/
 * ******************************************************************************
 * All rights reserved
 * Please keep this attribution intact
 * ******************************************************************************
 */
(function($){
    // **********************************
    // ***** Start: Private Members *****
    var pluginName = 'Placemaker';
    var config = {
        appID: ''
    }
    // ***** Fin: Private Members *****
    // ********************************

    // *********************************
    // ***** Start: Public Methods *****
    var methods = {
        config: function(obj) {
            $.extend(config, obj);
        },
        getPlaces: function(data) {
            var that = this;//jQuery object
            var def = new $.Deferred();
            if(config.appID === '') {
                def.rejectWith(this, [{message: pluginName + ' plugin application ID is not set'}]);
                return def.promise();
            }
            var query = [
                'select * from geo.placemaker where documentContent="' + data.text + '" and documentType="text/plain"'
            ];
            if(data.locale) {
                query.push('and inputLanguage="' + data.locale + '"');
            }
            query.push('and appid="' + config.appID + '"');
            var url = [
                'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query.join(' ')),
                'format=json',
                'env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env',
                'callback=?' // callback=Placemaker.retrieve ????
            ];
            $.ajax({
                url: url.join('&'),
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                cache: false
            }).done(function(o) {
            if(o.query && o.query.results && o.query.results.matches) {
                    def.resolveWith(that, [o.query.results.matches, data]);
                }
                else {
                    def.rejectWith(that, [{message:'no locations found'}]);
                }
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                def.rejectWith(that, [{message: textStatus}]);
            });
            return def.promise();
        }
    };
    // ***** Fin: Public Methods *****
    // *******************************

    // *****************************
    // ***** Start: Supervisor *****
    $.fn[pluginName] = function( method ) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || !method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' + method + ' does not exist in jQuery.' + pluginName );
        }
    };
    // ***** Fin: Supervisor *****
    // ***************************
})( jQuery );
```

### Setting the appID

```
You can hard-code your appID in your own copy of the plugin or set it like this :

    $().Placemaker('config', {'appID': '..........'});
```

Note that `.Placemaker()` needs to be invoked on a jQuery object. For the 'config' method, any selector will do, so an empty jQuery object, `$()` will suffice.

### Using the Plugin

The rest of your code, including a plugin call, will look like this :

```
$(function() {
    // *** fixed data ***
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.74651, -39.46289),
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var templates = [];
    templates[0] = '<div><h2 class="firstHeading">%user</h2><div>%text</div><div><a href="%url" target="_blank">%url</a></div><div>Date Posted- %date</div></div>';
    templates[1] = '<table width="320" border="0"><tr><td class="user" colspan="2">%user</td></tr><tr><td width="45"><a href="%profile_img"><img src="%profile_img" width="55" height="50"/></a></td><td width="186">%text<p><a href="%url" target="_blank">%url</a></p></td></tr></table><hr/>';
    templates[3] = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=false&screen_name=%val&count=10&callback=?";
    $$ = { //cache of jQuery objects
        news_tweets: $("#news-tweets"),
        user_banner: $('#user-banner')
    };

    // *** functions ***
    function news_tweets(value1) {
        $$.news_tweets.empty();
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); //??
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        $.getJSON(templates[3].replace('%val', value1), function(data) {
            var d, len = data.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var item = data[i];
                d = {
                    text: item.text,
                    user : item.user.name,
                    date: item.created_at,
                    profile_img: item.user.profile_image_url,
                    url: (item.entities && item.entities.urls && item.entities.urls.length) ? item.entities.urls[0].url : '',
                    locale: null
                }
                d.$tweet = $(templates[1].replace('%user', d.user).replace(/%profile_img/g, d.profile_img).replace('%text', d.text).replace(/%url/g, d.url))
                    .appendTo($$.news_tweets.css("overflow", "scroll"))
                    .find(".user")
                    .Placemaker('getPlaces', d)  //.Placemaker('getPlaces') returns a promise
                    .done(function(o, d) {
                        var m = ($.isArray(o.match) ? o.match[0] : o.match) || {};
                        if(m.place) {
                            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(m.place.centroid.latitude, m.place.centroid.longitude);
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                icon: d.profile_img,
                                title: d.user,
                                map: map,
                                position: myLatLng
                            });
                            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: templates[0].replace('%user', d.user).replace('%text', d.text).replace(/%url/g, d.url).replace('%date', d.date)
                            });
                            function openInfoWindow() {
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', openInfoWindow);
                            this.each(function() { //`this` is already a jQuery object. Re-wrapping as `$(this)` is not necessary.
                                $(this).on('click', openInfoWindow).css({'color':'#900', 'text-decoration':'underline', 'cursor':'pointer'});//$(this) is an individual tweet in #news_tweets.
                            });
                            bounds.extend(myLatLng); //??
                        }
                    }).fail(function(err) {
                        console.log(err.message);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    // *** event handlers ***
    $("#newsTypes").on('click', 'img', function() {
        news_tweets($(this).data('type'));
        //user_tweets("euronews");
    });
});
```

At the heart of this, you will find the following structure :

```
for(...) {
    var d = {...}; //object map comprising both data and options
    $(htmlString).appendTo(...).find(...).Placemaker('getPlaces', d).done(fn{}).fail(fn{});
}
```

It is important to note that :

- the jQuery method chain starts with a standard jQuery object.
- from `.Placemaker('getPlaces', d)`, methods in the chain return a jQuery promise object.
- in both the `.done()` and the `.fail()` handler, `this` is equivalent to the original standard jQuery object.
- the data map passed as the second argument in the expression `.Placemaker('getPlaces', d)`, reappears as the second argument of the `.done()` handler. This feature allows us to call `.Placemaker('getPlaces', d)` in a for loop without needing to specifically put the data into a closure or storing it in the DOM with `.data()`. In this regard, the 'getPlaces' method effectively serves as a closure as well as providing the required asynchronous lookup behaviour.

All this will be judged as thoroughly confusing or totally clever depending on your point of view.

Comment: ak, I've just made a couple of edits so be sure to pick up the latest code.

Comment: I said that i wont use your code and i didnt :) Your code was very helpful for me but a bit advanced. I found the solution to my problem today and i fixed it. The problem was google map was being drawn 2 times and I couldn't see the results of the news div. So I had to merge the two arrays together and load the function once. Many thanks for your help though I will call you if I need anything else :)

Comment: Sorry if i have wasted your time @Beetroot-Beetroot .

Comment: No worries ak, I'm just intrigued as to how and why your solution works. I can only think that your version of Placemaker.js is drastically different from the one I started off with. Hopefully the code above will be useful to future visitors here.

Comment: Beetroot can you help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446776/request-twitter-api-without-entering-a-loop.!!

Comment: My starting point would be the answer I gave you above, so I don't think I can be much use to you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see your code is written to `.replace()` the contents of the div's through each iteration. You need to add some indexing to your template array.

Try something like:

```
var index=0;

var templates = [];
templates[index]={
'0':'<div><div></div><h2....',
'1':'<table width="320".....',
'2':'<div><div></div><h2....',
'3':'<table width="320"....'
}
```

Then put your `Placemaker.getPlaces` block in a `for loop`
You update your templates with `templates[index]["0"]=whatever`.
I think this the logic you should be pursuing. Hope this all helps.

Comment: what if the function is coming from a loop? can u check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ang3lo0o/B9es7/ .I tried your suggestion but is not working